# JS base64 encode wav binary file

Tags: javascript, base64, speech-to-text, recorder

I need to encode to base64 a wav binary file that I get with the famous
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs project:

```
function ($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    var gumStream;
    //stream from getUserMedia() 
    var rec;
    //Recorder.js object
    var input;

    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    //new audio context to help us record 
    var recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton");
    var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
    $scope.properties.value = undefined;
    var srConfig = {"config":
        {
            "sampleRateHertz":16000,
            "languageCode": $scope.properties.languageCode
        },
        "audio": 
            {"content":""}
            
    };
        /* Disable the record button until we get a success or fail from getUserMedia() */


    this.startRecording = function(){
        console.log("recordButton clicked");

        var constraints = { audio: true, video:false };
        recordButton.disabled = true;
        stopButton.disabled = false;
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
            console.log("getUserMedia() success, stream created, initializing Recorder.js ...");
            document.getElementById("formats").innerHTML="Format: 1 channel pcm @ "+audioContext.sampleRate/1000+"kHz";
            /*  assign to gumStream for later use  */
            srConfig.config.sampleRateHertz = audioContext.sampleRate;
            gumStream = stream;
            /* use the stream */
            input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            rec = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1});
            //start the recording process
            rec.record();

            console.log("Recording started");
            setTimeout(function(){
              ctrl.stopRecording();
            }, parseInt($scope.properties.secondsToRegister)*1000);

        }).catch(function(err) {
            //enable the record button if getUserMedia() fails
            console.log("Error in getUserMedia");
            console.log(err);
            recordButton.disabled = false;
            stopButton.disabled = true;
        });
    };

    this.stopRecording =function(){
        console.log("stopButton clicked");
        //disable the stop button, enable the record too allow for new recordings 
        stopButton.disabled = true;
        recordButton.disabled = false;
        //tell the recorder to stop the recording 
        rec.stop(); //stop microphone access 
        gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
        //create the wav blob and pass it on to createDownloadLink 
        var response = rec.exportWAV(this.callDetectorService);

    };
    
    this.callDetectorService = function(blob){
              var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
              if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
                  console.log("withCredentials supported");
              }
              else{
                  console.log("withCredentials NOT supported");
              }
              var response;
              xhr.onload=function(e) {
                  if(this.readyState === 4) {
                      console.log("Server returned: ", e.target.responseText);
                      $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.properties.value = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
                      });
                      
                      response = e.target.responseText;
                  }
              };

              srConfig.audio.content=btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(blob)));
              console.log(srConfig);
              xhr.open("POST",$scope.properties.serviceUrl+"?key="+$scope.properties.secretkey,true);
              var data = JSON.stringify(srConfig);
              xhr.send(data);

    };
    

}
```

When the request is submitted (line xhr.send(data)) I get then the following error:

Server returned:  {
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding..",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

This let me think that the mistake is in the line that makes the encoding:

srConfig.audio.content=btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(blob)));

Thank you

Comment: When you just tell us what you want with some pseudo code it gives the impression you want us to write code for you. Instead show us what you have tried and on which part you have problems, then you might get help. I recommend to read [ask] .

Comment: I was thinking that adding the whole code could add too much of detail and not to focus on the important part that is how to encode an audio file. I'm sorry for that, I'm going to add all the code as requested, thanks for your help!

Comment: you don't need to add all the code, but the part that causes problems for you in form of a [mre] and a clear description of the problem.

Comment: Opps I read to late... should I remove some part?

Comment: you can and should alsways edit your question to improve it. The important thing is that the reader of the question get's a clear understanding about the problem. Therefore *is not working* is usually also not really helpful. The reader needs to guess here: does it give a) a wrong result (how did you come to that conclusion?) b) no result c) compile error (details?) d) runtime error/exception (details?)

Comment: you're right, I added the error returned, where we see that I have an encoding issue